How to set JaCoCo report name with Quarkus?
Currently, when running tests in Quarkus (./mvnw test) the JacoCo report is generated. However, when opening target/jacoco-report/index.html, the h1 tag is filled with the first test class that is run instead of the name of the project.

Is there a reason why artifactId is not used?
How to set the name?

PS: in jacoco.xml it's <report name=""></report>

Please update the question and specify how do you use JaCoCo. Do you use Quarkus extension or the JaCoCo Maven plugin? Attached pom.xml would be the best.

Yes, I use the Quarkus JaCoCo  extension quarkus-jacoco (default usage. Nothing fancy or complex)

In Quarkus ecosystem there are two ways to measure code coverage with JaCoCo.
Using Quarkus JaCoCo extension
According to the documentation

This Quarkus extension takes care of everything that would usually be done via the JaCoCo Maven plugin ...

However it's true it maybe configures JaCoCo a slightly different way then the jacoco-maven-plugin does.
To customize root node of the report just add this extension to pom.xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

and set this configuration property in application.properites
quarkus.jacoco.title=My Awesome Project's coverage report

More configuration options are available here.
Using jacoco-maven-plugin
This Maven plugin has a configuration property title to customize the root name of the report.
According to the goal's documentation

Default value is : ${project.name}

And ${project.name} also has default value: ${project.artifactId}.
So, to customize (override) the root name of the report using jacoco-maven-plugin

set project's name in the pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>code-with-quarkus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Awesome Quarkus App</name>
</project>

or

configure jacoco-maven-plugin's report goal

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.12</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                  <goals>
                       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <exclClassLoaders>*QuarkusClassLoader</exclClassLoaders>  
                    <append>true</append>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>

               <execution>
                  <id>report</id>
                  <goals>
                       <goal>report</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <configuration>
                    <title>Here comes an overridden title</title>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Thanks for answering. Then my only question would be why quarkus.jacoco.title is not defaulting to project.name (for consistency, which defaults to project.artifactId`). Maybe that can be suggested to Quarkus' team?

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/40993
